# Sinatra list of image files works on localhost but not on the test server

Tags: ruby, sinatra, thin

The code below gets a list of images from the public/images directory, creates an array of hashes and converts it to JSON then returns to the caller.

The code works perfectly on the local host - I get the list of image names as needed.

I then uploaded the code to my VPS and ran it on the same environment, running on thin, and nothing is returned at all. No matter what I change, either the path or method for getting filenames, like using `glob` instead of just `Dir`, nothing works that I tried.

Here is the code in the route I call from the client-side JavaScript using Ajax:

```
# get all images
get '/debug/posts/images/' do
  puts '>> debug > posts > images > get'

  all_images = Array.new

    # build substitute prefix path 
  uri = URI(request.url)
  prefix ='http://' + uri.host
  if request.port
    prefix += ':' + request.port.to_s
  end
  prefix += '/content/'

  begin
    content_type :json
        # get list of images
    pics = Dir['public/images/*']
    pics.map { |pic|
            # build hash for use with tinyMCE
      pic.split('/')
      pic_hash = {:title => File.basename(pic).to_s, :value => prefix + File.basename(pic).to_s}
      all_images.push(pic_hash)
    }

        # convert to json
    pic_json = JSON.generate(all_images)    
    body(pic_json)
  rescue Sequel::Error => e
    puts e.message
    status(400).to_json
  end
end
```

I get an array of values back running on the localhost:

```
[ {title: "bear-love.jpg"value: "/content/bear-love.jpg"}, {title: "bear-love2.jpg"value: "/content/bear-love2.jpg"}...]
```

I get an empty array from the VPS:

```
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Check that the server is being run as a user who has permission to read and execute public/images
2. verify that public/images exists
3. verify that public/images is where you think it is.

Comment: Permissions makes sense to try - public is the default path to serve up files - I am not even serving files just a list of file names so maybe read permission is an issu
2. and 3. have been verified as the site would not work at all without a correct structure

I'll look into the perms though, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it's easier to get the current path on the server and simply get a list of the image filenames I needed that way and just add my prefix path for use from the browser.